# unable to integrate/(combine its processes) Paypal Adaptive Payment

Tags: php, paypal-adaptive-payments

1. I made an pay request and got this response :--

[image]

Copied the redirect url with pay-key and paid .

2. I  made an execute payment request and got

message : [Message] => payKey AP-5NA540825A497342U has already been used to make a payment
[image]

3 . I tried to verify the transaction by making call to paymentdetail api that gives no error
[image]

I am using curl to make request.

using : https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library/archive/master.zip library for code sample

Please help me to complete the paypal adaptive payment process.

Comment: please open images in new tab to view bigger.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you must be using a paykey that was included with one of my samples..??  Like the error says, those have already been used for a payment so they can't be used again.

You need to start with the blank /templates/Pay.php file.  Get that setup with your own data, and then when that gets run it will generate a fresh paykey for you.

Comment: No I am not using the sample paykey provided in your docs.There was no need to call execute_payment api after sending request for pay perhaps only need to redirect to redirect_url that has come with pay requst .   Thanks(you are really doing good).

Answer (score 0):

I am getting same error, I have found solution.

When you care creating pay request (Like `Pay.php` in sample) you are using 'PAY' as Action Type so your payment is done when you are getting success message.

Now you don't need to execute payment. (Like `ExecutePayment.php` in sample).